# Bootstrap 3 pull and push issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with pull and push, I think it's because of the combination with offset?
What I want to do: (I can't post image because of the lack of reputation...)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypokV.png

After first problems and searching I've found out that better approach is mobile first (I know) so I've changed the layout accordingly. For the bigger browsers I need the second and third cells to switch their position.

So the first cell on the bigger screens always has 2 offset and then the size of 4. the other two also should have a size of 4 and after they switch, the one on the next line should also have an offset of 2.

I've tried all the number combinations I could think of but it is not working. Please help:/ One of my solutions:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-offset-2 col-md-4"></div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-push-6 col-md-4"></div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-md-pull-6"></div>
```

Comment: why use push or pull? You could achieve that easily without it

Comment: will you tell me something more? Because this isn't helpful at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that following achieves what you require using nested grid row:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-offset-2 col-md-4">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12" style="background-color:gray;">aaaa</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12" style="background-color:green;">bbbb</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4" style="background-color:lavender;">cccc</div>
</div>
```

Both listings on left are using offset 2 on bigger screens and retain size of 4 (as does the right column). On smaller screen sizes they all jump to full row width while keeping the desired order.

Comment: This solution is correct, works perfectly. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

dont bother.. forget about pull/push, you dont need them but you need to understand bootstrap grid system first.
here is the example

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-md-offset-2"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-md-offset-2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I understand the grid. Well, obviously not if I can't do what I want but... What is this suppose to do? This doesn't change the position based on the screen size, this isn't what I'm asking.